# How to know which user completed web/server side OAuth 2.0 flow initiated by a client such as a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, laravel, web, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a Chrome Extension, and it's using personal access tokens (Laravel Sanctum) to authenticate the extension/user with the backend/server API. So basically when sending requests to the endpoints from the extension I'm including the Authorization header with the Bearer token.

I want to add some third party integrations which will use OAuth 2.0 for authentication, and I want those integrations to be connected with the user on the backend (server) and not the extension itself. Basically, my server (API) will be a proxy between the integration API and the extension.

In the extension, when a user tries to connect an integration, a window opens and my server redirects the user to appropriate integration authorization URL (with my client id, scope, redirect uri, etc.) where the user can then authorize my app. After that's done the user is redirected to the provided redirect_uri (my domain) with the authorization code.

What is a smart and secure way to know which user (my user, not integration's) connected the integration, considering that my user identification (including the token for communicating with my API) is stored locally on the extension, and is not immediately available in the OAuth flow.

My idea is, when opening the OAuth window, pass the user data to my server (GET or POST), store a cookie, and then redirect to the integration's authorization URL, and when the user authorizes my app and gets redirected to the redirect_uri, my user data will be available in the cookie so that I can assign the authorization code to the appropriate user. Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there ever a time that an unauthenticated user would use the third party integration, such as an anonymous visitor on your web app? If not then I think you are on the rigght track.